# How to Adjust Index Column Width and Add a Vertical Line Separator?

Tags: two-column, indexing, imakeidx, idxlayout, gap

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
This is a sentence to be indexed.\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!\textbf{Subheading}!\lipsum[8]}

\idxlayout{columns=2}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

with the output:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I adjust the gap between the two columns and add a visible vertical line which divides the columns?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you just need to read page 3 of `idxlayout`'s documentation. However, you should read `imakeidx`'s documentation, too, for information about the various ways this may go wrong.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex[columns=2]
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\idxlayout{rule=1pt,columnsep=10pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
This is a sentence to be indexed.\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!\textbf{Subheading}!\lipsum[8]}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The results are fairly ugly, but demonstrate the principle:

[image: ugly demo]